# What is -inf in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, xlwings, infinity

I have a code that basically calculates the energy loss from the battery and the result is late pasted in excel using xlwings. The code that I have is perfectly fine but the only problem is that for the extremely small value it is print some wiered number in the excel `65535` and when I print it in the console it says `-inf`. My code is:

```
chargeKW = -0.0000000000463
dischargeKW = 0.00000000000250
chargeEff = dischargeEff = 0.95
powerRating = 0
scale = 1

energyLoss = chargeKW - (chargeKW * chargeEff) + (dischargeKW / dischargeEff - dischargeKW) / (100*powerRating * scale)
print(energyLoss)
```

Now I know this will give the error of `division by zero` but the whole code is very big that's why just for the explanation purpose I pasted the values and the formula here. So can anyone please tell me what is `-inf` or `65535`? I just want the 0 value if the value is too small.

Comment: `-inf` is negative infinity

Comment: how do I take care of it?

Comment: @nipunvats: Don't perform math that massively overflows (e.g. dividing reasonable sized numbers by numbers incredibly close to zero, or multiplying absurdly huge numbers together) beyond what even fully exponent scaled IEEE-754 binary64 floating point can represent. `inf` occurs when both operands have the same sign (both positive or both negative), `-inf` when the signs differ (one positive, one negative). Example, `-1 / 1e-320`. You probably have some really large or really tiny values hiding in there.

Comment: If those truly huge numbers are actually necessary to get an accurate result, the `decimal` module with manually adjusted `prec` (precision) can do the work (slowly), or the `fraction` module might apply (lossless, but can get truly insane on memory usage and/or equally slow when the values involved can't be reduced by GCD-ing). In most cases that's not necessary, the code (or inputs) just has a bug that's sending your calculations off into the "insanity" range.

Comment: A note: `(dischargeKW / dischargeEff - dischargeKW) / (100*powerRating * scale)` should be dying with a `ZeroDivisionError` every time, as written. `powerRating` is `0`, so the divisor is always `0`.

Comment: can I round it off to zero? I mean yes I don't need those huge numbers.

Comment: @nipunvats: You want to *round* the most negative "number" in the universe to zero? That's not "rounding"; by definition the numbers are infinitely far apart. If you have some incredibly tiny divisor involved that you'd rather drop to zero, you might apply a `round(expression_that_produces_divisor, 18)` or something prior to division, so [incredibly tiny numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) (by your program's logic, effectively zero) round to zero, so you get `ZeroDivisionError` instead of `inf`/`-inf`.

Comment: yeah, this makes sense now. thanks.